# type of usage with phrases

Tags: grammar, american-english, spoken-english

He finished the race and won a gold medal, **a fitting conclusion to his career.**

He finished the race and won a gold medal, **fitting conclusion to his career.**

When we use determiners with noun phrases is this to stop the reader from thinking, in this instance *fitting*, the phrase is not modifying anything else in sentence, even though it doesn’t it this instance anyway.
Just curious as to what the determiners role is in these instances.

As opposed to phrases that don't require the determiners such as:

She ran quickly to work and arrived on time, **clearly sweating from the heat.**

Comment: These sentences are different, because the sweating refers to **she**, while conclusion refers to **the race**, and not to **he**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that you're using a noun in the first instance, and a verb in the second.

You could say "He finished the race and won a gold medal, concluding his career." Something about using the gerund makes that all right, I'm not sure of the rule. So "sweating" or "clearly sweating" are all right, but using a noun form of "sweating" would not be.